# How to replace a whole word without changing any other matching strings?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to change all instances of the variable `Status` to `status` in my code.

However there are some lines where `Status` is on the same line as strings like `Current_Status` and `Check_Status_After_Write`, etc.

I want to replace the variable name only, and not change definitions of other variables or matching comment strings if possible.

I tried to use:

```
grep -nwrs Status ./Status.txt  | xargs sed -i 's/i\<Status\>/status/g'
```

This returns:
    sed: no input files

I tried simplifying it to use:

```
grep -rl Status ./Status.txt  | xargs sed -i 's/i\<Status\>/status/g'
```

But this fails to work as I wanted.

Am I over complicating this? Can anyone offer a solution?

As an aside, I've had a few failed attempts to do this and am a bit paranoid about the string replacement, is there a way to ask for verification before the replace happens without writing a script?

Comment: Why don't you try this `sed 's/Status/status/g' file`?

Comment: Yes you are over complicating it. Use word boundary. `sed 's/\bStatus\b/status/g' file`. Use `-i` option to make in-file changes.

Comment: Cheers jaypal, that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

can you not use the pattern

```
^Status$
```

to match only the word status, with nothing before or after it?

Comment: This will fail in this sentence `Status ok` without space at the beginning

Comment: the dollar sign should ensure it only matches where status is also the end of the line. Status matches the beginning and end, with nothing allowed in the end, that should work right? I'm genuinely confused if that doesn't work.